# How to set time to dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss in go?

Tags: parsing, datetime, time, go

https://play.golang.org/p/82QgBdoI2G

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("01-JAN-2006 15:04:00"))
}
```

The output should be like if date time today is `2016-03-03 08:00:00 +0000UTC`
Output: `03-MAR-2016 08:00:00`
Time should be in 24hr format.

Comment: BTW, in the playground the time is always 2009-11-10 23:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your layout is incorrect, it should show how the reference time is represented in the format you want, where the reference time is `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006`.

Your layout should be:

```
"02-Jan-2006 15:04:05"
```

Note the `05` for the seconds part. And since you specified the hours as `15`, that is 24-hour format. `3` or `03` is for the 12-hour format.

```
fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("02-Jan-2006 15:04:05"))
```

For me it prints:

```
03-Mar-2016 13:03:10
```

Also note `Jan` for months, `JAN` is not recognized. If you want uppercased month, you may use [`strings.ToUpper()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ToUpper):

```
fmt.Println(strings.ToUpper(time.Now().Format("02-Mar-2006 15:04:05")))
```

Output:

```
03-MAR-2016 13:03:10
```

Also note that on the Go Playground the time is always set to a constant when your application is started (which is `2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC`).

Answer (score 2):

```
fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("02-Jan-2006 15:04:05"))
```

See [Time package constants](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants)

> The reference time used in the layouts is the specific time:
>
> Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006
>
> which is Unix time 1136239445. Since MST is GMT-0700, the reference time can be thought of as
>
> 01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700